# unable to checkout git branch - file is missing in my local environment

Tags: git

I'm trying to check out files in a git branch that I created.

I'm on the branch called 06-20-2018_branch on the command line.

When I list the files and directories in this branch on the command line on my local machine, there is a difference from what I see in the git web interface.

This what I see on the command line on my local machine:

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 tdunphy tdunphy  4894 Jun 15 09:57 aws_rotate_keys.sh
-rwxr-xr-x 1 tdunphy tdunphy 21094 Jun 15 09:57 aws_rotate_my_keys.sh
-rwxr-xr-x 1 tdunphy tdunphy 49978 Jun 23 11:31 aws_utils.sh
-rwxr-xr-x 1 tdunphy tdunphy 49960 Jun 21 15:11 aws_utils.sh~
-rwxr-xr-x 1 tdunphy tdunphy 47854 Jun 15 09:57 aws_utils.sh.bak
drwxr-xr-x 3 tdunphy tdunphy  4096 Jun 20 21:10 singletons
drwxr-xr-x 4 tdunphy tdunphy  4096 Jun 20 21:00 source_files
drwxr-xr-x 2 tdunphy tdunphy  4096 Jun 15 09:57 text
```

And this is what I see in the web interface for this branch:

```
.vs
Directory singletons
Directory source_files
Directory text
File aws_jf_utils.sh
File aws_rotate_keys.sh
File aws_rotate_my_keys.sh
File aws_tools.sh
File aws_utils.sh
File aws_utils.sh.bak
```

I am missing a file called 'aws_jf_utils.sh' on my local machine.

If I try to do a git pull, it tells me that I'm already up to date with this branch:

```
Already up to date.
```

Git status shows:

```
git status
On branch 06-20-2018_branch
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 6 commits.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)

nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

Checking out that one file called aws_jf_utils.sh gives me:

```
git checkout aws_jf_utils.sh
error: pathspec 'aws_jf_utils.sh' did not match any file(s) known to git.
```

If I check out the one branch again, I get this:

```
git checkout 06-20-2018_branch
Already on '06-20-2018_branch'
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 6 commits.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)
```

How can I get at that one file I need called aws_jf_utils.sh?

Comment: try `git log --diff-filter=D --summary`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this command `git checkout origin/<branch-name -- path/to/aws_jf_utils.sh`

The issue is likely that the file was deleted in the last 6 commits on your local version of the branch. As you stated above, the file is still there in remote.

You were close with `git checkout aws_jf_utils.sh` you just needed to specify that you wanted to check the remote repo for the file.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Cool! That did the trick. And I got this message:

` git checkout origin/06-20-2018_branch 
Note: checking out 'origin/06-20-2018_branch'.

You are in 'detached HEAD' state. You can look around, make experimental
changes and commit them, and you can discard any commits you make in this
state without impacting any branches by performing another checkout.
If you want to create a new branch to retain commits you create, you may
do so (now or later) by using -b with the checkout command again. Example:
 git checkout -b <new-branch-name> HEAD is now at 9ec9903 added new files`